# How can I enable layout designer for Android, Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just reinstall Eclipse, and have got 1 problem: when I click on layout.xml file, designer(Graphical Layout) design isn't showed! Instead designer I see table with columns "Note/Content", without set of items and visual editor on "Design" tab; "Source" tab contains source code. How can i enabled visual designer?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

> Window → Preferences → General → Editors → File Associations

and select *.xml and then press Default on the Android Layout Editor entry in the list of associated editors.
[image]

Comment: But there are listed all the XML editors under the *.xml extension. How to make layout xml to be opened exactly with the layout editor?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem and had to right-click on a layout xml and then choose `Open With|Android Layout Editor`
I don't know how to fix it permanently when I reinstalled everything again the porblem has gone until that I right-clicked as above

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file, then select Open With -> Android Layout Editor